# Need Flow to Send Three Emails to Specific People

Tags: workflow

I've finally gotten my 30 day Flow to work and kick out an email.

How do I edit the Flow to include the same action at 60 and 90 day periods?

Also, how do I reach back and get the email address to send the email to from another List (MemberList) not currently in the Flow; however, the MemberCertQualList (used in the Flow) and the MemberList do share MemberUniqueID (ID for Member) and MemberCertQualUniqueID (ID for each CertQual) columns.